# MFC Tab Control Issue: Disappearance on Enter Key Press

Tags: mfc

I am encountering a peculiar issue in my MFC application with a tab control. Within the tab control, I have four tabs, each containing several text boxes. The problem arises when I input text into one of the text boxes and press the Enter key. Instead of behaving normally, the entire tab disappears, leaving behind a blank white window. However, when I switch to another tab and then return, the original tab reappears, as if nothing had happened.

I have thoroughly checked my code, and I have not implemented any special handling for the Enter key press that would cause this behavior. It seems to be an inherent issue with the tab control itself or some unexpected interaction between the text boxes and the tab control.

Here are some additional details about my environment and setup:

I'm using Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFC) for my application's user interface.
The tab control is implemented using the CTabCtrl class.
The text boxes are standard MFC CEdit controls.
I have not overridden any default behavior related to tab controls or text boxes.
The disappearance of the tab occurs consistently every time I press the Enter key within a text box on any of the tabs.

[image: Become White like this]

Comment: Is the parent of the tab control and the dialog (presumably) hosting the tabs' controls the same? If not you would need to fix that.